# How to specialize codec to deserialize top level class with parametrized type?

Tags: java, mongodb

I have a MongoDB Aggregation Pipeline with $facet to paginate results. The result is two fields : totalRows (Integer) and currentPage (Array).

```
[
            {
                "$match" : {
                    "$and" : [
                        {
                            "dateTraitement" : {
                                "$gte" : ISODate("2018-01-01T01:00:00.000+01:00")
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "dateTraitement" : {
                                "$lte" : ISODate("2020-02-27T01:00:00.000+01:00")
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "$facet" : {
                    "currentPage" : [
                        {
                            "$skip" : 0
                        }
                    ],
                    "totalRows" : [
                        {
                            "$count" : "count"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "$unwind" : "$totalRows"
            },
            {
                "$project" : {
                    "currentPage" : 1,
                    "totalRows" : 1
                }
            }
        ]
```

I want to map this result in a Pojo :

```
@Data
public class PaginatedResults<T> {

    private List<T> currentPage;

    private Integer totalCount;

}
```

If I just try to use aggregate without customizing the registry (̀`collection.aggregate(pipeline, PaginatedResults.class)`), I have the following error :

```
PaginatedResults contains generic types that have not been specialised.
Top level classes with generic types are not supported by the PojoCodec.
```

How can I instruct the codec to use a specific class to deserialize the property `currentPage` in `PaginatedResults` as a `List<MyPojo>` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can register a custom converter. [Reference documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongo.custom-converters)

```
@Configuration
public class Converters {

  @Bean
  public MongoCustomConversions mongoCustomConversions() {

    return new MongoCustomConversions(
        Arrays.asList(
            new PaginatedResultsConverter()));
  }
}


@ReadingConverter
public class PaginatedResultsConverter implements Converter<Document, PaginatedResults<T>> {
    @Override
    public PaginatedResults convert(Document source) {
       //implement PaginatedResults manually here
    }
}
```

Comment: but how you handle the parameterized type of PaginatedResults in the converter ?

Comment: You have to deal with it manually. for example:
`String type = (String) source.get("type");
        switch (type) {
            case "Point":
                return new PaginatedResults<Point>();
            case "LineString":
                return new PaginatedResults<LineString>();;`